# Image processing using opencv in python

Tags: python-3.x

CAN ANYBODY PLEASE HELP ME IN WRITTING A PYTHON CODE FOR  DETECTING  WHETHER AN OBJECT HAS FALLEN DOWN FROM A REFERENCE POINT OR COORDINATE EX : IN A LEMON RACE WHEN A LEMON FALLS DOWN FROM SPOON THAN MY CODE SHOULD DETECT THAT LEMON HAS FALLEN DOWN

ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 0):

**Image Processing using opencv in python**

```
import cv2   
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)  ## Example
```

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html